# How to create Azure Feature Flag for the App Configuration through c# code?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-app-configuration, azure-feature-manager

I am using .net core 3 to create configuration setting in App configuration. I was able to create a key-value in the configuration explorer using the following code snippet and some additional configuration in the link below

```
var client = new ConfigurationClient(_configuration.GetConnectionString("AppConnectionString"));
var settingToCreate = new ConfigurationSetting(model.Key, model.Value);
client.SetConfigurationSetting(settingToCreate);
```

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/appconfiguration/Azure.Data.AppConfiguration/README.md#create-a-configuration-setting

I am currently working on creating a feature flag in feature manager pane of App Configuration using the same approach but providing the contenttype for featureflag as below.

```
var client = new ConfigurationClient(_configuration.GetConnectionString("AppConnectionString"));
var settingToCreate = new ConfigurationSetting(model.Key, model.Value);
settingToCreate.ContentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.appconfig.ff+json;charset=utf-8";
client.SetConfigurationSetting(settingToCreate);
```

The issue is it creates a feature flag but without a name, showing an error message as below
[configuration explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WJAn.png)

[feature manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aafbf.png)

Please suggest any possible solutions. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Please see [this sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/appconfiguration/Azure.Data.AppConfiguration/samples/Sample9_FeatureFlags.md) for managing feature flags with the .NET SDK for App Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I find you can add `.appconfig.featureflag/new` by using `Azure App Configuration client library for .NET`.

But you can't create `.appconfig.featureflag/new` in configuration explorer on portal. You can check the image like below. You also can try in your side.

[image]

#### So I think this is a problem with the library and there are no restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement the entire end-to-end scenario for **feature flag management and usage**. You can find the post [here](https://medium.com/@vikasshankari93/feature-flag-management-and-usage-in-azure-app-configuration-using-c-net-ec12cb23c49d)